# Jquery infinite scroll only works on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm implementing lazy load on a page with a grid, and it works great, but only after the page is reloaded.
Can anyone advise on how to set up a DOM so that this doesn't require a reload to run?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      {%- if paginate.next -%} {
      $('.posts--grid').jscroll({
        loadingHtml: "<div class=\"loading-container\"><img src={{ 'loading-data.gif' | asset_url }}</div>",
        nextSelector: '#posts--grid--next-page:last a.posts-next-link',
        contentSelector: '.posts--grid',
        autoTrigger: true,
        padding: 300,
        callback: function() {
          if($('#posts--grid--next-page').children().length <= 0) {
            $('#posts--grid--next-page').remove();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
    {%- endif -%}
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You said infinite scroll works after page reload. At what point does it stop working, before the page reload? And what triggers the page reload? Are you manually reloading the page?

Comment: Hi - yes and thank you for your note. On initial page load, the lazy load does not run. The default pagination appears ("next" link). But if I manually reload the browser, the lazy load script functions perfectly and the products in the "next" page load as expected as I scroll down the page.